# Can one show that ${\gamma^5}^\dagger = \gamma^5$ directly from the anticommutation relations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, representation-theory, dirac-matrices

Is it possible to show that ${\gamma^5}^\dagger = \gamma^5$, where
$$ \gamma^5 := i\gamma^0 \gamma^1 \gamma^2 \gamma^3,$$
using only the anticommutation relations between the $\gamma$ matrices,
$$ \left\{\gamma^\mu,\,\gamma^\nu\right\}=2\eta^{\mu\nu}\,\mathbb{1},$$
and *without* using any specific representation of this algebra and a unitary invariance argument, as is usually done?

Comment: you need to know that $\gamma^{\mu \dagger}=\gamma^{\mu}$ for all $\mu=0,1,2,3$, then it's straight forward.

Comment: Martin: How do you show that?

Comment: Isn't $\gamma^{1,2,3}$ anti-hermitian?

Comment: It depends on the representation you choose.

Comment: $\gamma^{\mu\dagger}=\gamma^0 \gamma^{\mu} \gamma^0$ and $[\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}]_+=2\eta^{\mu\nu}$. For +--- metric, $\gamma^0$ is Hermitian and $\gamma^i,i=1,2,3$ is anti-Hermitian. For -+++ metric, $\gamma^0$ is anti-Hermitian and $\gamma^i$ is Hermitian. Perhaps it is not due to representation.

Comment: Without the information of Hermicity of gamma matrices, how to ensure the Hermicity of  Hamiltonian in Dirac equation?

Comment: Well, an odd number of gamma matrices will switch sign under hermitian adjoint, and the $i$ will take care of the sign. The anti-commutation relation will take care of re-ordering all the terms.

Comment: Related meta post: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5258/2451

Comment: What are you willing to assume about the hermiticity of the other gamma matrices? If you don't have some such hypothesis, then what exactly do you mean by ${}^\dagger$, then?

Comment: @CrazyBuddy This question is not off-topic. Qmechanic also thinks the same. See his comment on this [meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5258/the-gamma5-question).

Comment: @user10001: Done. After Emilio's revision, I think it's worthy to reopen. Cheers :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the comments explained, you need to know a few properties of the $\gamma$ matrices. First of all, from 
$$ \{\gamma_\mu, \gamma_\nu\} = 2 \eta_{\mu \nu} \mathbf{1}_4$$
you can infer that (depending on the metric but **not** on the representation of the dirac algebra!) in (+---) metric
$\gamma_0$ is hermitian (hint: look at the $\mu = 0, \nu = 0$ component of the above equation), while the $\gamma_i$ ($i = 1, 2, 3$) are anti-hermitian. (In -+++ metric, this would be interchanged). And this should allow you to solve the problem.

The hermicity properties can be condensed into
$$ \gamma_\mu^\dagger = \gamma_0 \gamma_\mu \gamma_0$$
which just reproduces the above if you take the commutation properties into account.

Comment: Dear Neuneck, thanks for your response. I'm missing one thing: how do you show that $(\gamma^0)^2=\mathbb{1}$ leads to $(\gamma^0)^\dagger = \gamma^0$, and that $(\gamma^j)^2=-\mathbb{1}$ leads to $(\gamma^j)^\dagger = - \gamma^j$?

Comment: @Psycho_pr I think the easiest way to see it is that is true for the Dirac representation (as detailed on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices)) and use the fact that all representations of the Clifford algebra are unitarily equivalent, i.e. related by a transformation $$\gamma_\mu \to U^\dagger \gamma_\mu U$$ with $U^\dagger U = \mathbf 1$, which leaves the hemicity properties invariant.

Comment: Hrmm, but if we are going to look at a particular representation anyway, why did we need to know that $(\gamma^0)^2 = \mathbb{1}$ and that $(\gamma^j)^2=-\mathbb{1}$? We could have just shown directly the hermiticity properties in the Dirac (or Weyl) representations and then shown it remains invariant under unitary transformations. Am I missing something?

Comment: The full proof involves showing that the gamma matrices are the basis of a (finite dimensional representation of an) infinite group. Therefore they must be unitary and using this in addition to the relations I gave implies the conjugation properties. -- Sorry that I didn't mention this before.

Comment: I guess you tried to follow Peskin's QFT, p50 "The matrix $\gamma^5$ has the folllowing properties, all of which can be vertified using (3.68) and the anticommuting relation (3.22)". I don't think that's enough. One has to use the Hermicity properties of gamma matrices. The Hermicity properties of gamma matrices is a requirement for the Hermicity of Dirac Hamiltonian. It's natural to use them. Once we adopt the Hermicity of gamma matrices, the proof of $\gamma^{5\dagger}=\gamma^5$ is straightforward.

Comment: You can prove the Hermicity (and anti-Hermicity) from the old-fashioned Dirac equation, $H=\mathbf{\alpha} \cdot \mathbf{p} + \beta m$ (under +--- metric), $\gamma^0:=\beta, \gamma^i:=\beta \alpha^i$, $\beta^{\dagger}=\beta$, $\alpha^{i\dagger}=\alpha^i$ and the anticommuting relations of $\alpha,\beta$ matrices.

Comment: @user26143, that's exactly what I tried to do. At Neuneck: So if I understand correctly the scheme is like so: $(\gamma^0)^2=\mathbb{1}$ and $(\gamma^j)^2=-\mathbb{1}$ out of the commutation relations _and_ the gamma matrices must be unitary because of the reason you mentioned, _so_, together these two facts imply the Hermiticity relations. So with these two facts we never used any particular representation (except, maybe, when proving that the gamma matrices are unitary).

Comment: OK, if one could use the information of a particular representation (plus the unitary equivalence) then the Hermicity is a corollary... Nevertheless I would say the Hermicity is needed to justify Dirac representation is a correct representation......

Comment: Just a quick note, squaring to the identity does *not* imply a matrix is hermitian. A counterexample is $$M=\begin{pmatrix}-1&-2\\ \phantom{-}0&\phantom{-}1\end{pmatrix}.$$ Does this answer still hold in light of that fact?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, according to Neuneck, $\gamma^0$ is both idempotent _and_ unitary. These two facts together, supposedly, imply Hermiticity. Is this true?

Comment: Yes. For unitary matrices with $A^2 =1 $ we have  $$ A = A^{-1} = A^\dagger$$.

Comment: @user26143 You can check that the Dirac rep. is a 'correct representation' by brute forcing them through the anticommutation relations. As I mentioned, unitarity is a corrollary for finite dimensional reps of the clifford algebra (although I still can't name the theorem, sorry)

Comment: @Psycho_pr That much is correct. However, you should note that if you assume $\beta$ is hermitian then you're already there. Unless you admit a hypothesis relating the gamma matrices to the inner product structure you will never prove your result.

Comment: @Neuneck I am not sure if anticommuting relation of gamma matrices is sufficient for the Dirac equation, although one could say Dirac field is just spinor representation of Poincare group. From the Hamiltonian $$H= \int d^3 x \psi^{\dagger} [ - i \gamma^0 \vec{\gamma} \cdot \vec{{\nabla}} + m \gamma^0 ] \psi = \int d^3 x \psi^{\dagger} [  \gamma^0 \vec{\gamma} \cdot \vec{p} + m \gamma^0 ] \psi$$, to ensure $H^{\dagger}=H$, I need the Hermicity of $\gamma$. Would you provide a reference that unitarity is corrollary for finite dimensional reps of the clifford algebra? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try using the definition of $\gamma^5$ and just apply the conjugation. Remember that conjugation flips the order of the matrices, which means you want to change their order before applying the conjugation.

Then realize that the anticommutation relations give you a way of interchanging two gamma matrices, giving only a minus sign (provided the indices are different).

Lastly, note that, independent of your convention, you have an uneven number of anti-hermitian matrices in this expression (while the rest is hermitian).