# Adjoint of Gamma Matrices - Dirac

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation

I just started to learn how to quantise Dirac field. Meanwhile, as we can write the Dirac equation in terms of gamma matrices :

$$ (i\hbar\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m)\psi = 0  $$
where $\gamma_\mu$ matrices obey Clifford algebra
$$ \{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\} = \eta^{\mu\nu} $$

Now I just came across that the adjoint of the gamma matrices can be written as :

$$ \gamma^{\mu\dagger} = \gamma^0\gamma^\mu\gamma^0 $$
I already checked [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/89611/how-to-prove-gamma-mu-dagger-gamma0-gamma-mu-gamma0), but it doesn't suggest a way to prove it in a representation independent manner. Also the Wikipedia page suggests that gamma matrices are chosen such that they satisfy the above relations, since they are arbitrary upto a similarity transformation.

So is that the way this identity comes, or is there something else ?

Comment: Also related: [Can one show that ${\gamma^5}^\dagger = \gamma^5$ directly from the anticommutation relations?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88572/can-one-show-that-gamma5-dagger-gamma5-directly-from-the-anticommutat)

Comment: Thanks ! So this is true because that these relations satisfy the commutation relation in the {+---} notation, right ?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you mean by "prove it in a representation independent manner". What are you prepared to take as hypotheses? It's important to note that **the anticommutation properties alone are not enough** to prove that formula, because they have no relation at all to any inner product (and thus adjointness) structure. You need some additional structure, such as unitarity of a representation, to be able to prove it at all. The proof will then depend on what that additional structure is.

Comment: No, that question is ill-defined. See my comments there: [#1](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88572/can-one-show-that-gamma5-dagger-gamma5-directly-from-the-anticommutat#comment181299_88572), [#2](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88572/can-one-show-that-gamma5-dagger-gamma5-directly-from-the-anticommutat#comment181385_88577).

Answer (score 4):

You may use one of representations, then - prove the relation $\gamma_{\mu}^{+} = \gamma_{0}\gamma_{\mu}\gamma_{0}$ in this representation, and finally prove that it is correctly for an arbitrary representation (as I think that you want to see 
just that).

Here I will use the spinor representation:
$$
\gamma^{\mu} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \sigma^{\mu} \\ \tilde {\sigma}^{\mu} & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad \sigma^{\mu} = (\hat {\mathbf E }, \sigma ), \quad \tilde {\sigma}^{\mu} = (\hat {\mathbf E }, -\sigma ).
$$
It's not hard to show that in this representation 
$$
{\gamma^{\mu}}^{+} = \gamma^{0}\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{0}. \qquad (1)
$$
Then let's introduce the unitary transformation $\Psi \to \hat {U} \Psi, \bar {\Psi} \to \bar {\Psi}\hat {U}^{+}$, which connects spinor and some other basis. Corresponding transformation of the gamma-matrices is $\gamma^{\mu} \to \hat {U}^{+}\gamma^{\mu}\hat {U}$. Lets see how does $(1)$ change under this transformation:
$$
{\gamma^{\mu}}^{+} \to (\hat {U}^{+} \gamma^{\mu} \hat {U})^{+} = \hat {U}^{+} {\gamma^{\mu}}^{+}\hat {U} = \hat {U}^{+} \gamma_{0}\gamma^{\mu}\gamma_{0}\hat {U} = \hat {U}^{+}\gamma_{0} \hat {U} \hat {U}^{+} \gamma^{\mu}\hat {U} \hat {U}^{+}\gamma^{0}\hat {U}=
$$
$$
=\tilde {\gamma}^{0}\tilde {\gamma}^{\mu}\tilde {\gamma}^{0}.
$$